# copy rich text from a window

Tags: perl, copy-paste

I need to copy the rich text from the window of a program under windows OS.

If I drag and drop the text into wordpad (ctrl-c doesn't work), I get the correct results, using a specific greek font; but it doesn't work at all under perl. I think that it depends on the fact it is rich text.

In the following code, I've tried all the possible permutations of the rows preceded by the ### and the result is always the same, showing many question marks instead of the greek formatted text.

Can you help? Thanks

```
use 5.016;
use Win32::GuiTest
qw( FindWindowLike GetWindowRect GetWindowID GetClassName WMGetText GetWindowText UnicodeSemantics);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode qw (from_to decode encode);

UnicodeSemantics(1);

###
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
###
#binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
###
open 'FILE', ">", "canc.txt";
###
#binmode(FILE, ":utf8");

my $hwnd = 131266;
my $info = "# Window Text: '" . GetWindowText($hwnd) . "'\r\n";
$info = $info . "# Window Class: '" . GetClassName($hwnd) . "'\r\n";
$info = $info . "# Window ID: " . GetWindowID($hwnd) . "\r\n";
my ( $left, $top, $right, $bottom ) = GetWindowRect($hwnd);
$info = $info . "# Window Rect: ($left, $top) - ($right, $bottom)\r\n";

say $info;
my $actualText = WMGetText($hwnd);
say $actualText;
say FILE $actualText;
###
my $foo = decode( 'UTF-8', $actualText );
say $foo;
say FILE $foo;
###
my $body = encode( 'UTF-8', $foo );
say $body;
say FILE $body;
```

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html

Comment: What codepage is using for you text? In windows there are three codepages: OEM, ANSI, Unicode. OEM for console applications, ANSI -  singlebyte encoding for Win API and unicode - utf16 for WinAPI. I think source text has utf16 encode.

Comment: @RachelGallen, thanks, I've tried but it make no difference :-(

Comment: @KostiaShiian I've tried your suggestion, using utf16-le/be, but it is still gibberish. Only when I drag and drop the text directly into wordpad it shows correctly. Don't know it this adds something, but if I drag and drop the text into the url bar of the browser, and then I copy and paste into wordpad, the text is correct.

Comment: Ok. Try save $actualText in file without any manipulation. Then open this file in web browser and change codepage until the text will became clear.

Comment: $actualText doesn't contain the correct text either....

Comment: Anyway it is utf-8, gvim tells me so...

Comment: The contents of your *document* may be UTF-8, but that doesn't (necessarily) mean that your WMGetText will necessarily return data in that format. (In fact, I don't think Windows ever uses UTF-8 internally?)

Comment: I've tried also by running the program in ubuntu, under wine... same result.